# Sass Not Precompiling on Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline, Assets:precompile rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline, assets

I've got an app I just converted to Rails 3.1. In my app/assets/stylesheets I have a bunch of sass files that use @import to import parial sass files. One of these files is called screen.sass and it's the main sass file that I want to use in one of my layouts.

However, when I run

```
RAILS_ENV=demo bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get that screen isn't precompiled
  (in ../app/assets/stylesheets/screen.sass)

It wasn't getting compiled at all with no message without adding this to demo.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( screen.css )
```

I've tried several things like renaming the screen.sass file to screen.css.sass and I've tried creating a manifest file called screen.css in my app/assets/stylesheets directory and requiring the screen.sass file. In each case I get the same precompile error for it as above.

I'm not precompiling with the production environment because demo is my staging environment I want to test the 3.1 upgrade on.

Anybody have any ideas as to what else I can try to fix this error?

Comment: I know this is super old but I'm actually seeing this same issue with rails 4.  Many (most) sass files are being precompiled correctly but one isn't, oddly it works in development and gets compiled on the fly but completely ignored by `assets:precompile`

Comment: Looks like I needed the file to be called `blah.css.sass` *and* I needed `config.assets.precompile += %w( blah.css )` even though the config comment says "...all non-JS/CSS are already added"

Answer (score 2):

rake assets precompile needs to know what type of file to compile your stylesheet to. Change screen.sass to screen.css.sass

Comment: Do you have config.assets.compile = true in your demo.rb?

Comment: I'd try setting it and config.assets.compress to true.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to have some kind of effect. It's trying to compile, but it just hangs when it gets to that sass file. I'm not sure how to debug that. I took out everything in the file but a few lines of css and it still hangs. Ever seen that?

Comment: Nope. As the [Rails Guide says](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), "Always specify an expected compiled filename that ends with .js or .css,
even if you want to add Sass or CoffeeScript files to the precompile array."